# Combining IFERROR and LEFT Formulas

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, left-join

I have a formula that looks like this

```
=IFERROR(B83,"OPEN")
```

So if a certain cell has an error it changes it to OPEN, but if it doesn't then it returns the values within that cell.

I am trying to make the cell also short the text that is being returned to 7 characters.

I made this formula:

```
IFERROR(B83,"OPEN"),AND(LEFT(B83,7))
```

However it does not work and instead returns an "NA".

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
IFERROR(LEFT(B83,7),"OPEN")
```

You need to put your desired result as the first argument of IFERROR.